# Knockout click data-bind not firing

Tags: knockout.js

I know it must be super easy for you. But I have been looking for this code for hours and cannot see where I did wrong.

I'm trying to show 2 input when a list item is click with its value. But nothing work.
So I tried just to put a simple button with a click event. Yet it still does not fire. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
<!--HTML-->
<input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.onClick">

//JS
//that the basic. the full code in jsfiddle
function Workers(){
        self = this;
        self.onClick = function() {
            alert('2');
        };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new Workers());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cr7cy36m/

Thanks a million!
Ran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `self` a local variable instead of a global by declaring it with `var`:

```
function Workers(){
    var self = this;
    self.onClick = function() {
        alert('2');
    };
}
```

Without the `var`, `self` in that function is the same `self` as you have in the `Worker` function, so its value gets overwritten with the `Worker` version.

See http://jsfiddle.net/cr7cy36m/1/